# Android > 4.0 Fragments and Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I am really lost here.

I want to make an app that will have tabs ( fragments? ).
So whenever a user clicks on a tab, a new fragment is loaded.

The UI would be similar to the one under View Control -> Fixed Tabs here : http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

I don't need backward compatibility.

I have no idea how to proceed as I am really confused.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a nice tab navigation example on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html).  If you don't need backward compatibility then you don't have to modify it and can use it right away.

Comment: either I have no idea what I'm saying, or you didn't read my question carefully. I don't want backward compatibility

Comment: Ohh, sorry I read that you *need* backward compatibility. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can quite easily create a sample app with Fragments linked to Tabs in Eclipse:

- File > New > Android Application
- Choose Min SDK API 14, targetSDK API 17. Click Next. Click Next again.
- Create your icon. Click Next.
- Tick Create Activity. Choose Blank Activity. Click Next.
- Click Navigation Type. Choose Tabs, or Tabs + Swipe, or whichever option you want. Click Finish.
- You're done. You have a fully functioning sample app with source for Fragments and Tabs.

Comment: This is backward-compatible solution and forces user to refer to the Support Library in the project.